# How to disable MFC macros that change function names for Unicode or ASCII

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, mfc, static-libraries

MFC has defines such as

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define DrawText  DrawTextW
#else
#define DrawText  DrawTextA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

However I am using a library which also has DrawText() function and I guess MFC defines change that as well and I am getting linker error for this call because obviously the library has no function with the name DrawTextW(...)

How can I make the library function work in my MFC application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not MFC, but rather the Windows API. The prescribed way to work around macros that shadow other symbols is to **temporarily** disable the macro:

```
// Temporarily undefine the DrawText macro
#pragma push_macro("DrawText")
#undef DrawText

// Call your version of DrawText
DrawText( ... );

// Re-enable the macro
#pragma pop_macro("DrawText")
```

#pragma [push_macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bs04eza.aspx) and [pop_macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsttss76.aspx) are necessary to not break the Windows SDK headers.

The same scheme should be applied in the header and implementation files for your class. If you cannot change the header file for this class, you need to wrap the `#include` directive in a push/undef/pop sequence:

```
#pragma push_macro("DrawText")
#undef DrawText

#include "my_header.h"

#pragma pop_macro("DrawText")
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple preprocessor hack should do the job. But you should be careful to limit WHERE you use it as it could mess up MFC. So you should limit the use to where you need to access that library.

```
#ifdef DrawText
#undef DrawText
#endif
```

Comment: This results in `error C2039: 'DrawText' : is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfPainter'`. Than I thought maybe I should just undefine it and define it again to self as `#define DrawText DrawText` but I get same error with that too.

Comment: This is going to be rather annoying, you need to undef it **JUST** for the call to the other library, and then redefine it correctly

Comment: You'll have to undefine it after the MFC headers are included, but before the `PoFoDo` library headers are included.  Otherwise when the library headers are processed the compiler will incorrectly see that `class PoDoFo::PdfPainter` has a `DrawTextW()` member function instead of a `DrawText()` member function.

Comment: To whomever downvoted... please post a reason, this is a perfectly valid answer to the question.

Comment: -1 You are contradicting yourself. Even though you state that the scope of the *"preprocessor hack"* should be limited, you provide nothing to actually do so. You further correct your proposed solution in the comments, stating that you have to *"redefine it [the macro] correctly"*, but again, provide nothing to actually implement this. Overall, this is a bad approach, appying a global solution to a local problem.

Comment: This question is tagged [visual-c++]. A compiler-specific solution should not come as a surprise. This question is tagged [mfc] as well, which implies MSC. If - on the other hand - you know of a way to re-enable a macro, that does not rely on compiler-specific implementations, don't hesitate to update your answer. Be sure to re-enable the macro to the true value it was holding, not to the value you assume it should have been. Good luck finding a compiler-agnostic way to implement this.

Comment: @IInspectable not disputing that, the current state of portable (even on the same platform) C++ is pretty atrocious. That doesn't mean my answer is any less valid, although overall yours is better (and the votes reflect that).

Comment: [`#pragma push_macro`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bs04eza.aspx) is not Microsoft-specific. [Intel supports it](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/index.htm#GUID-392F7939-278C-4EE7-BAE3-55F9AB42759F.htm). [GCC supports it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html). Regardless, I would always favor a compiler-specific solution over one that breaks a build. Portability is not a feature that customers are terribly crazy about.